# What does Roger Miller say at the end of "Kansas City Star"

Tags: lyrics, roger-miller

What does Roger Miller say at the end of [*Kansas City Star*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBeXnzjvMrk)?

It seems to be an aside, a "parenthetical comment" at the very end, the last two seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a google search, it is apparently:

*Stay tuned, gonna have a Popeye cartoon in a minute.*